# AWS Glue Exclude Patterns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I am working on a project which is using Glue 3.0 & PySpark to process large amounts of data between S3 buckets. This is being achieved using [GlueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html) to read the data from an S3 bucket to a DynamicFrame using the recurse connection option set to True as the data is nested heavily. I only wish to read files which end in meta.json therefore I have set the [exclusions filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude) to exclude any files which end in data.csv `"exclusions": ['**.{txt, csv}', '**/*.data.csv', '**.data.csv', '*.data.csv']` however I am consistently getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling o90.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Unable to parse file: <filename>.data.csv
```

Is it possible to log the full S3 uri to the output logs or keep a track of the files which have/have not been processed? What is the reason it is still trying to parse this file even though it is included in the exclusions?

Comment: I investigated with the Python [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob) module and found that `**/*.csv` matched all CSV files regardless of nested depth or dir location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclusions has to be a string

```
"exclusions": "[\"**/*.txt\", \"**/*.csv\"]",
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Relevant documentation : 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-s3-home.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-s3